# Create rounded fire effect on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, svg, canvas, gsap

Stumbled a pretty fire effect in [**Hobbit's**](http://middle-earth.thehobbit.com/mirkwood/battleground) site.This effect I saw actually only in game's.

There are have two block's with `left` and `right` side (`evil` and `good`)

[image]

When you hover one of this block there are have rounded circle of fire

like in bottom

**FROM**

[image]

**TO**

[image]

I created something like that but actually my fire is not showing smoothly like in the site above.I need exactly the same effect like in site please help.

```css
.good {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/gapib8/good_icon.png);
  background-size:cover;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:10px;
}
.good .ring {
  overflow:hidden;

  transition: 1s opacity;
  transition-timing-function:easeInOut;
  opacity:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eJCQpT/fire_ring.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;


}
.good:hover .ring {
  opacity:1;

}
```

```html
<div class="good">
  <div class="ring">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BramVanroy It's missing the "rotation" effect in the original version.

Comment: You'll want to look at clip-path, and animate that. Probably a triangle that is animated from 0deg to 360deg or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is heavyweight WebGL solution using fragment shader

```html
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/gapib8/good_icon.png">
<div class="zone"></div>
<canvas width="335" height="335" id="canvas"/>
<script type="glsl">
precision highp float;
uniform float time;     
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float fill;      // fill of fire ring (0-1)

vec3 firePalette(float i) {
    float T = 1400. + 1300.*i; 
    vec3 L = vec3(7.4, 5.6, 4.4); 
    L = pow(L,vec3(5.0)) * (exp(1.43876719683e5/(T*L))-1.0);
    return 1.0-exp(-5e8/L); 
}    

vec3 hash33(vec3 p) { 
    float n = sin(dot(p, vec3(7, 157, 113)));    
    return fract(vec3(2097152, 262144, 32768)*n); 
}

float voronoi(vec3 p) {
// https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/voronoilines/voronoilines.htm
 vec3 b, r, g = floor(p);
 p = fract(p); 
 float d = 1.; 
 for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
     for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
      b = vec3(i, j, -1);
      r = b - p + hash33(g+b);
      d = min(d, dot(r,r));
      b.z = 0.0;
      r = b - p + hash33(g+b);
      d = min(d, dot(r,r));
      b.z = 1.;
      r = b - p + hash33(g+b);
      d = min(d, dot(r,r)); 
     }
 }
 return d;
}

// https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/warp/warp.htm
float noiseLayers(in vec3 p) {
    vec3 t = vec3(0., 0., p.z+time*1.5); 
    const int iter = 5; 
    float tot = 0., sum = 0., amp = 1.; 
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        tot += voronoi(p + t) * amp; 
        p *= 2.0; 
        t *= 1.5; 
        sum += amp; 
        amp *= 0.5; 
    }
    return tot/sum; 
}
    
float sdPie( in vec2 p, in vec2 c, in float r ) {
    p.x = abs(p.x);
    float l = length(p) - r;
 float m = length(p - c*clamp(dot(p,c),0.0,r) );
    return max(l,m*sign(c.y*p.x-c.x*p.y));
}
    
void main(void) {
    float f = (1.-fill)*3.1415;
    vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy - resolution.xy*0.5)/ resolution.y;
    float cs = cos(f-time/4.), si = sin(f-time/4.);
    uv.xy *= mat2(cs, -si, si, cs); 
    vec3 rd = normalize(vec3(uv.x, uv.y, 3.1415/8.));
    float c = noiseLayers(rd*2.); 
    float d = dot(uv, uv);
    float ts = 0.105 + sin(time)*0.001;
    float ring = 1. - min(smoothstep(d, 0.11, ts), smoothstep(d, ts, 0.11));
    vec3 col = sqrt(clamp((firePalette(c*ring)-0.03)*1.5, 0., 1.));    
    if (fill<1.)
      col *= sdPie(uv,vec2(sin(f+0.001),cos(f+0.001)), 0.5)*3.1;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(col, ring);  
}
</script>

<script>
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,3,-1,-1,3,-1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader(`attribute vec2 v;void main(void){gl_Position=vec4(v,0.,1.);}`,gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
shader(document.querySelector(`script[type="glsl"]`).textContent,gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'resolution');
let time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
let fill = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'fill');
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(time, t/1000);
  gl.uniform1f(fill, getComputedStyle(canvas).opacity);
  gl.uniform2f(resolution, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n").map((s, i) => (""+(1+i)).padStart(4, 0)+": "+s).join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
</script>

<style>
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: -29px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: -26px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.zone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 19px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 245px;
  height: 245px;
}

div.zone:hover + canvas{
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. It should be replicating the animation on the website.

EDIT: updated with clipping to provide the circular revealing effect, which works on Firefox too :)
It is not using the same asset as the original website, so the effect is admittedly not as good. By replacing the asset you should be able to get the same, including the sparkles at the end of the revealing effect.

```css
.good {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/gapib8/good_icon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  position: 
}

.good .ring {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.good .ring img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.good .ring .fire-reveal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.2%;
    left: 3.6%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/cNZZG8/fire_ring_complete.png);
    background-size: 588px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -150px -300px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

.good:hover .ring .fire-reveal {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    animation: reveal 0.4s cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 51% 63%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 100% 57%, 51% 63%);
  }
  12.5% {
clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 51% 63%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 51% 63%);
  }
  25% {
clip-path: polygon(49% 37%, 49% 30%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 51% 100%, 51% 50%);
  }
  37.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% 63%, 51% 63%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 51% 63%);
  }
  50% {
clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 50% 54%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50%);
  }
  62.5% {
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 52% 53%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 42%);
  }
  75% {
  clip-path: polygon(48% 0, 49% 50%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  }
  87.5% {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 46% 30%, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  }
  100% {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 45%, 100% 57%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  }
}

.good:hover .ring img {
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  animation: rotation 20s linear both infinite;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.9);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="good">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="fire-reveal"></div>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eJCQpT/fire_ring.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are 100% right. I initially looked at the site in Firefox, and it doesn't behave the same as in Chrome. Will have another go

Comment: Updated with circular revealing effect.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution
Its not the same like website.

You are free to modify the values of the timings for the animation

I added spinning animation to the fire

```css
.good {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/gapib8/good_icon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.good .ring {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s opacity;
  transition-timing-function: easeInOut;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eJCQpT/fire_ring.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.good:hover .ring {
opacity:1;
  animation: spin 2800ms linear 0ms infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
   /* opacity: 0; */
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* opacity: 0; */
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
   /* opacity: 0; */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="good">
  <div class="ring">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the OPs description and example, an infinite animation loop is required.

Comment: @Script47 yup exactly

Comment: @GautamNaik the animation in site something like filling up but youre just coming from nowhere..I need exactly like in site like filling up.After when it filled up it start's to round.